# ASP.NET and C# Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am working on a project for school, and this is an extra credit part. I have a project started in VS 2010 using master pages, and what I'm trying to do is get a "Submit" button to redirect people to the "MyAccounts.aspx" page. My current code for the ASP part for the button looks like this:

`<asp:Button ID="btnTransfer" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>`

I have tried adding in the `OnClick` option, as well as the `OnClientClick` option. I have also added this code to the Site.Master.cs file as well as the Transfer.aspx.cs file:

```
protected void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveClientUrl("/MyAccounts.aspx"));
}
```

When I run this and view the project in my browser, the whole thing runs fine, but when I click on the "Submit" button, it just refreshes the current page and does not properly redirect to the MyAccounts page. Anyone have any ideas for me?

Comment: sorry, the asp portion for the button is currently <asp:Button ID="btnTransfer" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>

Comment: ...try Response.Redirect("~/MyAccounts.apsx");

Comment: I've tried that, it still just puts a box in the bottom right that flickers real quick and says "Waiting for localhost...." it goes away and stays on the same page.

Comment: Considering downloading [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com). It will be a very good debugging resource during your studies.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are doing it almost correctly, you just haven't put the correct pieces together. On Transfer.aspx, your button should be:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTransfer" OnClick="btnTransfer_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
```

and your code behind should be like what @KendrickLamar said:

```
protected void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/MyAccounts.aspx");
}
```

The `OnClick` event tells it what to execute on post-back when the users clicks the button. This is in the code-behind for Transfer.aspx, not the site master.

Comment: try Response.Redirect("MyAccounts.aspx");

Comment: When I use that code though, I am getting a compiler error when I try to view it in web browser.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.transfer_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnTransfer_Click' and no extension method 'btnTransfer_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.transfer_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1325850 like I said, the function needs to be in the transfer.aspx code behind (transfer.aspx.cs).

Comment: namespace Unit3GP
{
    public partial class Transfer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/MyAccounts.aspx");
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user1325850 That error means that you do not in fact have it in the correct code behind file. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: What does your @Page directive look like?  Is it possible that the relationship is broken between your aspx and codebehind?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Transfer" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Transfer.aspx.cs" Inherits="Unit3GP._Default" %>

Comment: @user1325850 that should be `Inherits="Unit3GP.Transfer"`.

Comment: It seems like your Inherits attribute is incorrect if your class is called Transfer.  I would change that to Unit3GP.Transfer and see if it resolves your problem

Comment: got it. when you asked me about the @page directive, i totally missed that the pages inherit Default. so i put the btnTransfer_Click event in the Default code behind file and it works fine.

Comment: @user1325850 no... you change the inherits to be correct like we said... you don't have some random code behind executing for a page. That is confusing.

Comment: Just curious, why have you decided to put it in Default rather than in the Transfer codebhind and fix the @Page directive?  Mix n' matching isn't a good WebForms best practice. (did I misunderstand?)

Comment: no no no, i guess i didn't explain that right. i did change the inherits to the Transfer page, and put the code in the proper place

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - didn't mean to try and steal credit.  I've seen people take comments and propose them as answers so I thought it was a SO norm.  I removed my answer.  You deserve the credit for troubleshooting.  sorry about that

Comment: @Scott Well you definitely helped. I have been going through your other answers to see what to vote up. If I hadn't already posted the inherits stuff it would've been OK, since that differed enough from my original answer ;)

Comment: @Scott you weren't totally wrong in what you did. Typically you will see many similar answers that were all answered at the same time, it just matters on time and who explains it best on who gets most votes. But in this case it was same as my comment, which is why I wondered why you posted separately. No worries.