# Redirect to index page after logging in using c#

Tags: c#, redirect

Currently, I am developing a website. I am working to redirect the log in page to index page, after I check the credentials inputted on the textboxes element by the user on the database. If the database has an data equal to the user credentials then it should be redirected to the index page. but i dont know how to do it with c#. Also, this is the code I am working with. Can someone help me to do the redirection of the page after logging in?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string loadApplicantAccount(string user, string pass)
{

    GlobalDeclarations gd = new GlobalDeclarations();
    List<emplInfo> mylist = new List<emplInfo>();
    using (mysql.MySqlConnection connection = new mysql.MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        mysql.MySqlCommand cmd = new mysql.MySqlCommand("spLoadApplicantAcc", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("uEmail", mysql.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("uPword", mysql.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

      mysql.MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            mylist.Add(new emplInfo
            {
                Displayname = dr["Displayname"].ToString(),
                FullName = dr["Fullname"].ToString(),
                Access = dr["Usertype"].ToString(),
                Status = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Status"].ToString())
            });
            gd.Sessions = dr["Fullname"].ToString();
        }
        Session[gd.AppUser] = gd.Sessions;
        dr.Close();
        connection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("index.html");
    }

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsn = jss.Serialize(mylist);
        return jsn;
    }

public class emplInfo {
    public string Displayname;
    public string FullName;
    public int Status;
    public string Access;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983545/asp-net-and-c-sharp-redirect/15983596

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");` will redirect to the Index.aspx page in the root of the application.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the response. but i am using .html
How to implement this code sir?

Comment: I assumed you were using WebForms and aspx pages. This would go in your code behind. I know see that loadApplicationAccount is a WebMethod. Are you calling loadApplicationAccount directly from your html? If so, you'd need to handle the redirect from there. (Set window.location or something like that.) This is a "not very C#" way of doing things. Is there a reason you're not doing a more typical ASP.Net with "code behinds"?

Comment: I am not using aspx sir. I used html. i just opened the dashboard template downloaded from web also i use jquery and javascript calling the web method